# BarChart Frame Labeling

Tags: charts

Given a list of integer values that represent the number of cliques in a large random graph, whose values I wish to display in a barchart.

```
 sizeCounts = {500, 50000, 1333938, 10683530, 27399408, 23442136, 6889918, 713994, 26984, 384}
```

My code for the BarChart is:

```
 BarChart[sizeCounts, ChartLabels -> Range[Length[sizeCounts]], 
  Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> Bold, FrameStyle -> Bold, 
  FrameLabel -> {"CLIQUE SIZE", "NUMBER OF CLIQUES"}]
```

The chart displays as I want, but I simply can't figure out how to
get the font of the frame label at the bottom of the barchart to
display as a bold font, like that I was able to get for the frame
label on the left side.

How can I get **both** the side and bottom frame labels to display in a bold
font?

This seems like a trivial question, but I've tried all sorts
of positions for wrapping the labels and other expressions in Style[*,Bold]
and using directives at various placements, but to no avail. I find no other
posted questions offering much in the way of clues.

Comment: looks like a version/os-related issue. (Works as expected in _Version 13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)_)

Comment: Running on Windows 11, 64 bit.

Comment: What Mathematica version are you using? (You can check `$Version` for the full version information)

Comment: Version 13.2.1.0.